# running jRuby cucumber acceptance tests in a Grails environment

Tags: grails, cucumber, jruby

It's great to be able to run
`grails test-app`, `test-app integration:`, `test-app unit:`, etc.

My team has some jRuby Cucumber acceptance tests. How can we run these similarly with a grails-script?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://grails.org/plugin/cucumber

Comment: That is only for Cucumber tests written with groovy steps...